# Rails & Docker "Compilation failed: bundle exec rails assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=XXXXX exit code: 1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, webpacker

I have an annoying error continuously when I run `docker-compose build` or `docker build .`

My Docker file:

```
...
ADD . $ROOT
RUN bundle exec rails assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Where I have a problem is this part:

> RUN bundle exec rails assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

Error Message is

```
 > [12/12] RUN bundle exec rails assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
#18 3.263 yarn install
#18 3.374 [1/4] Resolving packages...
#18 3.773 [2/4] Fetching packages...
#18 8.321 [3/4] Linking dependencies...
#18 10.98 [4/4] Building fresh packages...
#18 11.51 Done in 8.26s.
#18 13.31 Compiling...
#18 46.03 Compilation failed:
#18 46.03

executor failed running [/bin/sh -c bundle exec rails assets:precompile]: exit code: 1
```

These messages did not help me at all when I investigate why it happened.
Some say that it's caused by lacking memory, but how can I know from this error message and how to resolve it?
Any Idea for this error? Thank you in advance.

ADD:
I tried to `docker-compose build` after I comment out `bundle exec rails assets:precompile` in Dockerfile.
And then, I ran
`docker-compose run app bundle exec rails assets:precompile`
I got the same error

```
Compiling...
Compilation failed:

ERROR: 1
```